# Suggest merging of lock and security

Tags: discussion, retagging

[lock](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lock) seems like a sub-domain of [security](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security). Shouldn't we remove it?

Comment: Also [tag:theft]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. While questions about bike locks are security questions by nature, security questions are not necessarily lock questions. If we remove the lock tag and have them all fall under security, it would be more difficult to explicitly search for lock questions.

Comment: How about this: Can you set up security so it also brings up lock questions, but not the other way around?

Comment: What about security and theft?

Comment: @NeilFein I'm not sure if the mods can, but I know I can't.

Comment: @Vorac my gut says that they're different, but I can't vocalize why that is. Perhaps someone else will have an opinion.

Comment: @jimirings The mods can do it, but they'll likely hold off on this one unless there's a consensus.

Comment: @jimirings, it's just that there are too many tags for me. I have been here for 2 years now, and tag most of my questions with [tag:mountain-bike] and one more word, because there are 15 friggin pages of tags!

Comment: @Vorac I just did a quick random sampling of other SE sites and we have the fewest tags that I found on a non-beta site. Every other site I looked at had over 20 pages of tags, most over fifty, and Stack Overflow has a whopping 1025 pages of tags. Even the beta sites average about 10-15 pages of tags. We're actually pretty reserved.

Comment: I usually go the other way with tags - type in some useful-seeming terms and see what the autocomplete suggests. Possibly because I use SO so much that paging through the list never seemed like a useful idea.